# Editor plugin corrupting inline styles when saved to the database

Tags: devdemon, editor, redactor

Whenever I save content in Editor, and the content contains elements with inline styles, the attribute is corrupted. For example:

```
<div style="background:#eee;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:5px 10px;">This is a test</div>
```

When this is saved, the folllowing is added to the database

```
<div  solid #ccc;padding:5px 10px;">This is a test</div>
```

As you can see, the inline style attribute has been corrupted? This occurs whenever the content is saved

Comment: Wild guess, but could it be no space beteeen your declarations?

Comment: This was CSS generated by the editor